# How do I find out how my USB/harddrive has been formatted on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-11.04

I for some reason can't find anything on google that tells me how to figure out what my drive has been formatted to. Any search for my question gives me results for "how to format" and not "what my format is." By format I mean NTFS, FAT32, HFS+, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the command, as root or sudo -

```
fdisk -l
```

the usb driver is probably labled /dev/sdb like the below -

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        5737    46080000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2            5737        6375     5120000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3            6375       22565   130048000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb4           22565       38914   131319809    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5           22565       38914   131319808    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Or for a graphical version go to `System -> Admin -> Disk Utility`

Select the hard disk you are interested in, and all sorts of wonderful information will be visible.

[image]

Comment: For more information such type (vfat,fat,...): df -T